# MongoDB use of $match and $cond

Tags: node.js, mongodb

How to use $match and $cond together

```
{ $match:  { $cond: { if: deleted: { $ne: 1 }, then:{ d_id: d._id, sender_id: req.body.recipient_id }, else: d_id: d._id } } },
```

I would like to check if deleted field into database not equal 1 then it should check sender_id other wise it will only check d_id this is not working for me please guide

Comment: You can use the MongoDB query language's [$or] operator; e.g., `{ $or: [ { deleted: { $ne: 1}, d_id: d._id, ... }, { deleted: 1, d_id: d._id } ] }.

Comment: YOU CAN $and and $or need to use ?

Comment: See MongoDB documentation on: [$or](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/or/index.html) and [$and](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/and/index.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [$match](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/) docs:

> $match does not accept raw aggregation expressions,  Instead, use a $expr query expression to include aggregation expression in $match.

And from the [$cond](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/) docs:

> return one of the two specified return expressions.

So we can't really use aggregation expressions in `$match` like that, we have to use [$expr](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/expr/), like so:

```
{
    $match: {
        $expr: {
            $cond: {
                if: {$ne: ["$deleted", 1]},
                then: {$and: [{$eq: ["$d_id", d._id]}, {$eq: ["$sender_id", req.body.recipient_id]}]},
                else: {$eq: ["$d_id", d._id]}
            }
        }
    }
}
```

We can also just simplify it using boolean logic:

```
{
    $match: {
        $and: [
            {
                "d_id": d._id
            },
            {
                $or: [
                    {
                        sender_id: req.body.recipient_id
                    },
                    {
                        "deleted": {$ne: 1}
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```